# Select database by user?

Tags: php, database

I've create a php based program from where the user start program by selecting database year like 10-11, 11-12, 12-13 etc.. and my database name is like DB1011 for 10-11, DB1112 for 11-12 and so on.

now i have connect.php which is connection file which have

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123098ABC")
or die("Could not connect to the Server. Check your network connection : " . mysql_error());
$Db = "DB1112";
?>
```

now how can i do this that when user select database 11-12 then my program work in DB1112 until user not close program. and i want to do this without session if it's possible in PHP?

Thnx..

Comment: i know about mysql_select_db(dbname) but i want to know hot to do when user select year 10-11 then its select database DB1011 and if user select database 11-12 then its select DB1112

Comment: "and i want to do this without session" --- any **valid** reason for that?

Comment: is it not possible without session cause i've used too much session's in my program and i know it'll make some problem in session but if no other way then have to make it by session.

Comment: what problem? There are no any problems with sessions

Comment: why you need sooooo many different databases?

Comment: for fast processing it's good to be made yearly databases

Answer (score 1):

you can use `mysql_select_db()` to select the database.

```
$Db = "DB1112";
mysql_select_db($Db, $link);
```

more info here : https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the database using `mysql_select_db(dbname);`.